# React.js + D3.js - Nodes overlap each other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, tree

I have tree to show data. Can see here **[TREE](https://codesandbox.io/s/ov2jokvl1z)**

In big data when `A` **is expanded** children spread all the free space and **overlap each other**.  Then, if you open the next parent `Z` the children spread between sibling nodes, separation works `code-` **RadialTree.js** `63> separation={(a, b) => (a.parent === b.parent ? 1 : 5) / a.depth}` if the second parent is not open, the separation does not work.

How can solve this problem? so that when open only `A` or `Z` did not overlap each other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I added - `separation={(a, b) => ((a.children === b.children) && (a.parent === b.parent) ? 1 : 7) / a.depth }`

It works, but needs to be improved.